# Spreadsheet not found using service_account_file

Tags: python, pygsheets

Hi I plan to deploy an app that would log to spreadsheets. I used the [PyGSheets](https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets).

I get a raise.

```
raise SpreadsheetNotFound('Could not find a spreadsheet with title %s.' % title)
pygsheets.exceptions.SpreadsheetNotFound: Could not find a spreadsheet with title RSSI Spreadsheet.
```

after I used to authorize using service_account_file

```
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file='something.json')
```

But it works with

```
gc = pygsheets.authorize(client_secret='client_secret_something.json')
```

I would want to use the service_account_file so that it would pass authorization process.

Comment: if you are using service account make sure to share the sheet with that account. only then you can access then.

Comment: also what do you mean by pass the authorization process?

Comment: When you use the client_secret, it will generate some keys then need to copy and paste it.

Comment: Hey it worked, thanks! I shared it with the client email. Thanks!